# Which framework best supports highly customizable JSON serialization?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm looking for a framework that supports JSON (de-)serialization on a low level OR is highly customizable.

Many of the types of the object model I have to serialize must be created in a specific way and not all of the information is avaiable to a generic parser.
Currently I'm using JSON.Net with JSONConverters for most of the types, but the instantiation of the types is tricky and not very clean (private constructor with JSONConstructor attribute + post-construction Initialize method that supplies remaining construction data).

In short, a OR-Mapper is not ideal for me because:

- Objects are not POCOs (no default constructor, not all constructor information available in parser)
- Certain types can be expressed far more compact and readable than what a OR-Mapper creates (e.g. a value-type pair can be stored as `{"theType" : "theValue"}` instead of `{"type": "theType", "value" : "theValue"}` – the difference here is mostly readability)
- Changes to the domain model are difficult to support; i need to parse legacy data with an old parser to old POCOs, convert those to curernt POCOs and serialize with the current parser (at least I assume that's how it's done with OR-mappers)

When I wrote all the JSONConverters I realized that a framework that provides low-level serialization methods (WriteProperty, ReadValue, WriteObject) would be sufficient for me and also provides the flexibility to create more compact, readable JSON and allows me to 
create migrators for different versions of the domain model with little overhead (compared to needing legacy domain objects for ORM parsing).

**Are there any frameworks that support low-level / highly customized JSON parsing?**
I would rather not write such a parser myself, even though I suppose it would not be that difficult since JSON is a simple format (though Date parsing etc. will likely be a headache).

The JsonReader/Writer types of JSON.Net are basically what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if it'd be such a great idea to use these types in this way, resp. if there are other libraries that do a better job at providing this functionality – JSON.Net is after all intended to be used as ORM-parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question I'll post an answer myself, although I'd accept Soundararajan's answer if he gets the chance to complete his plans and provide his implementation.

I ended up using the JsonReader/Writer types of JSON.Net for the time being.

Once / if performance becomes an issue, I'll switch to protobuf-net which [supports SAX-like parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095991/can-i-use-protobuf-net-as-a-sax-like-parser-without-a-full-type-definition).

If someone knows a better library for highly customizable / SAX-like JSON serialization, feel free to leave an answer, I'll still watch this question.

Answer (score 1):

We used this [java library](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for JSON that is extremely configurable. We ported it to C# though. :)

Comment: That would be exactly what I'm looking for, too bad it's in Java. Did you publish your C# port of Jackson or know of a similar parser for C#?

Comment: Am sorry, that my organization won't allow me to do that. But i have plans for it now, but not too early :(.